# What does the typical notation of $n>N$ in a convergent sequence mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

This should be an easy question, but I'm not getting it. I assume that $n$ stands for the index but what is $N$? Please provide an easy explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. To improve clarity of your question, please include an example. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) link on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Here $n$ and $N$ are two positive integers.  The statement $n > N$ states that one of them is larger than the other.  It could be that $n$ can be used for the index in a sequence.  For example, I may say $2^{-n} < 1/1000$ for all $n > 10$.  (Here I let $N$ be $10$.)  My statement means $2^{-11}<1/1000$ and $2^{-12}<1/1000$ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're talking about the definition of convergence, something like this:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that for every $n > N$, $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.

So what is $N$?  It says if you give me any positive number $\epsilon$, I can give you a number $N$ representing a point $a_N$ in the sequence such that every member of the sequence past that one is within distance $\epsilon$ of $L$.